# Averaging Vertically in Nested Lists

Tags: python, list, nested

I am writing a grade book program that sets a nested list with assignments as columns and individual students along the rows. The program must calculate the average for each assignment and the average for each student. I've got the average by student, but now I can't figure out how to calculate the average by assignment. Any help would be appreciated! 
      # gradebook.py

```
# Display the average of each student's grade.
# Display tthe average for each assignment.

gradebook = [61, 74, 69, 62, 72, 66, 73, 65, 60, 63, 69, 63, 
62, 61, 64],
         [73, 80, 78, 76, 76, 79, 75, 73, 76, 74, 77, 79, 76, 
78, 72],
         [90, 92, 93, 92, 88, 93, 90, 95, 100, 99, 100, 91, 95, 99, 96],
         [96, 89, 94, 88, 100, 96, 93, 92, 94, 98, 90, 90, 92, 91, 94],
         [76, 76, 82, 78, 82, 76, 84, 82, 80, 82, 76, 86, 82, 84, 78],
         [93, 92, 89, 84, 91, 86, 84, 90, 95, 86, 88, 95, 88, 84, 89],
         [63, 66, 55, 67, 66, 68, 66, 56, 55, 62, 59, 67, 60, 70, 67],
         [86, 92, 93, 88, 90, 90, 91, 94, 90, 86, 93, 89, 94, 94, 92],
         [89, 80, 81, 89, 86, 86, 85, 80, 79, 90, 83, 85, 90, 79, 80],
         [99, 73, 86, 77, 87, 99, 71, 96, 81, 83, 71, 75, 91, 74, 72]]
#make variable for assingment averages
#make a variable for student averages
stu_avg = [sum(row)/len(row) for row in gradebook]
print(stu_avg)
#Assignment Class
class Assignment:
    def __init__(self, name, average):
        self.average = average
        self.name = name
    def print_grade(self):
        print("Assignment", self.name, ":", self.average)
#Student Class
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, average):
       self.average = average
       self.name = name
    def print_grade(self):
        print("Student", self.name, ":", self.average)
s1 = Student("1", stu_avg[0])
s2 = Student("2", stu_avg[1])
s3 = Student("3", stu_avg[2])
s4 = Student("4", stu_avg[3])
s5 = Student("5", stu_avg[4])
s6 = Student("6", stu_avg[5])
s7 = Student("7", stu_avg[6])
s8 = Student("8", stu_avg[7])
s9 = Student("9", stu_avg[8])
s10 = Student("10", stu_avg[9])

s1.print_grade()
s2.print_grade()
s3.print_grade()
s4.print_grade()
s5.print_grade()
s6.print_grade()
s7.print_grade()
s8.print_grade()
s9.print_grade()
s10.print_grade()
```

Comment: You seem to know how to get assignment #1; what is preventing you from using that same technique for the other assignments?

Comment: That was an error, it just printed [0] for each element in the list. I'll remove it.

Comment: Put it back!  But instead of `[0]` use `row[0]` instead.

Comment: Thanks so much! Any suggestions to get the averages to round to two decimals?

Comment: I still need help figuring out how to average the values in each column as well!

Comment: @MasonAdrales check if this helps. If you don't have numpy, install it with pip install numpy. You'll need it in large data-processing applications, and I thinks it's a good use of time to learn it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using loops, let's use matrices. They make calculation much much faster, especially when dealing with large datasets.

As an example,

```
Per student:

[1, 2, 3, 4]       [1]
[4, 5, 6, 6]   x   [1]
[1, 1, 3, 1]       [1]

Per assignment

[1, 2, 3, 4]T      [1]
[4, 5, 6, 6]   x   [1]
[1, 1, 3, 1]       [1]
```

The first operation returns per student sum, and the second returns per test sum. Divide appropriately to get the average.

```
Using numpy

import numpy as np

gradebook = [[61, 74, 69, 62, 72, 66, 73, 65, 60, 63, 69, 63, 62, 61, 64],
         [73, 80, 78, 76, 76, 79, 75, 73, 76, 74, 77, 79, 76, 78, 72],
         [90, 92, 93, 92, 88, 93, 90, 95, 100, 99, 100, 91, 95, 99, 96],
         [96, 89, 94, 88, 100, 96, 93, 92, 94, 98, 90, 90, 92, 91, 94],
         [76, 76, 82, 78, 82, 76, 84, 82, 80, 82, 76, 86, 82, 84, 78],
         [93, 92, 89, 84, 91, 86, 84, 90, 95, 86, 88, 95, 88, 84, 89],
         [63, 66, 55, 67, 66, 68, 66, 56, 55, 62, 59, 67, 60, 70, 67],
         [86, 92, 93, 88, 90, 90, 91, 94, 90, 86, 93, 89, 94, 94, 92],
         [89, 80, 81, 89, 86, 86, 85, 80, 79, 90, 83, 85, 90, 79, 80],
         [99, 73, 86, 77, 87, 99, 71, 96, 81, 83, 71, 75, 91, 74, 72]]


def get_student_average(gradebook):
    number_of_students = len(gradebook[0])
    number_of_assignments = len(gradebook)

    matrix = [1] * number_of_students 
    # [1, 1, 1, 1, ...]. This is 1 * 15. Need to transpose to make it 15*1

    # Converting both to numpy matrices
    matrix = np.array(matrix)
    gradebook = np.array(gradebook)

    # Transposing matrix and multiplying them
    print(gradebook.dot(matrix.T))

def get_assignment_average(gradebook):
    number_of_students = len(gradebook[0])
    number_of_assignments = len(gradebook)

    matrix = [1] * number_of_assignments 
    # [1, 1, 1, ...] . This is 1 * 10. Need to transpose to make it 10*1

    matrix = np.array(matrix)
    gradebook = np.array(gradebook)

    gradebook = gradebook.T
    matrix = matrix.T


    print(gradebook.dot(matrix))

get_student_average(gradebook)
get_assignment_average(gradebook)
```

Results

```
student_avg -> [ 984 1142 1413 1397 1204 1334  947 1362 1262 1235]
test_avg -> [826 814 820 801 838 839 812 823 810 823 806 820 830 814 804]
```